# Crystal Reports: only field headers showing up. No data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I'm new to CR (this is my first experience in fact). I'm trying to create a report based on a stored procedure I created in SQL Server 2012. 
The SP is relatively simple and it runs just fine within SQL Server: all the data is right there in the results.

However, when I created a new standard report in Crystal Reports (2013), I'm able to access my server and database, select the SP, and the fields I want to use. It goes smoothly until I select "Finish". When the report loads, there's only the field headers from the SP. 
I'm lost. I've tried it many times and continue to have no data. When I right-click to check the connection, it confirms connection. When I right-click on a field in the field explorer (I believe it's called) to view the data, there's nothing there.

The strange thing is, I created a view in SQL Server with the same query and when I added that view to CR, it worked fine. All my data was right there.

I also tried using a few other SPs in the database and I had the same issue —headers with no data, so I'm pretty confident it's not the SP itself.

Note: after selecting my SP and field when starting a new CR, I'm presented a window to choose the data range (which I assume is based on a date time parameter I have built into the SP). I didn't choose a date range because the end user will be selecting the range they need, so I checked the null boxes. I doubt if this plays any part, but I figured I'd mention it.

There must be something simple I'm missing here. I just don't get it. Any ideas? Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: what happens if you put the dates on?

Comment: Same thing: no data shows up.

Comment: can you post your report and also your sp thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but after putting the dates in again it worked out ok. I guess I just ninunderstood the way crystal reports works coming from SSRS. I thought putting the date parameters in when starting the report would somehow make those the static date parameters.

Answer (score 0):

put your code and SP so that i can identify